# HTTP and HTTPS impacts on SEO

Tags: seo, https

I have a website `http://www.domain_1.com/` hosted in a shared webserver. 
I have used SSL for another website `https://www.domain_2.com/` on the same server. 
Due to some technical limitations (single IP), if you try `https://www.domain_1.com`, browser will show the same `domain_2` website. But this is not a concern for me.

Question: will this scnario impact SEO of `domain_1` (non-HTTPS) site?

Comment: Google recently announced that using an SSL certificate will have a positive impact on Google rankings.

Answer (score 6):

<s>As a general rule, search engines do not crawl or index pages served over HTTPS. Having said that, if you search Google you will see some pages served over HTTPS in Google's index. To prevent this from causing you issues, use canonical URLs for your second domain's pages. That way when they are crawled the search engines using HTTPS and domain_1 will know that domain_2 is the primary domain for that content.</s>

Not only do search engines support SSL pages but [Google now uses them as a positive ranking factor](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.se/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html).